# Group member of a gitlab group can't have access to the group project

Tags: gitlab

I recreated a production problem like this:

"Group-A" has a project named "Project-A".
Another group named "Team" is a member (maintainer) of "Group-A".
The group "Team" has a user named "User-1".
The group "Group-A" has a member named "User-2" (maintainer).

When I check who has access rights to "Project-A", I don't see the group "Team". But when I log in with User-1 on Gitlab, I can access Project-A.

Is it a display bug or is it normal?

Actually, I try to synchronize the rights of the gitlab project with the sonarqube project, it works for User-2 but not for User-1.